# Can not replace values in pandas dataframe column with map

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace a column in pandas data frame using a dictionary and the map method.I found a method without map but its very very ugly

Here is my dictionary

```
{'A+': '97–100%',
 'A': '93–96%',
 'A−': '90–92%',
 'B+': '87–89%',
 'B': '83–86%',
 'B−': '80–82%',
 'C+': '77–79%',
 'C': '73–76%',
 'C-': '70–72%',
 'D+': '67–69%',
 'D': '63–66%',
 'D-': '60–62%',
 'F': '0–59%'}
```

and here is my data frame

```
Fname   Lname   MidExam FinalExam   CW1 CW2 TotalPoints StudentAverage  Grade
1   Velma   Paul    49% 66% 59% 78% 252 63.00%  D
2   Kibo    Mcgee   75% 75% 68% 66% 284 71.00%  C-
3   Louis   Underwood   98% 44% 67% 42% 251 62.75%  D-
4   Phyllis Clemons 65% 45% 65% 55% 230 57.50%  F
5   Zenaida Mcdowell    65% 54% 65% 54% 238 59.50%  F
```

and i want to replace the letters D, F, ... with numbers

After i use

```
df["Grade"] = df["Grade"].map(usa_grade_dict)
```

i get

```
Fname   Lname   MidExam FinalExam   CW1 CW2 TotalPoints StudentAverage  Grade
1   Velma   Paul    49% 66% 59% 78% 252 63.00%  NaN
2   Kibo    Mcgee   75% 75% 68% 66% 284 71.00%  NaN
3   Louis   Underwood   98% 44% 67% 42% 251 62.75%  NaN
4   Phyllis Clemons 65% 45% 65% 55% 230 57.50%  NaN
5   Zenaida Mcdowell    65% 54% 65% 54% 238 59.50%  NaN
```

I do not know why I am getting NaN instead of the actual number
Any help would be awesome ^^ Ty

Comment: What is `print (df['Grade'].tolist())` ?

Comment: Maybe whitespaces, then need `df["Grade"] = df["Grade"].str.strip().map(usa_grade_dict)`

Comment: Yep... there were whitespaces, thank you so much. Please post the comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If get missing values in output it means key of dicionary not match with values of column.

If problem with whitespaces in column use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df["Grade"] = df["Grade"].str.strip().map(usa_grade_dict)
```